# Adding space after every letter in R column

Tags: r, dataframe, split, tex

I Have data frame with 4 columns and I need to add space after each I so the values will split. Whole data frame has 8064 rows. Thank you.

```
   CustomerI    V1    V2     V3
1  1231231231   l22I34  l22   l22
2  1231231233   l7      l7I19 l7
3  1231231234   l31     l7    l31
4  1231231235   l31l7   l7    l31l7
5  1231231236   l16     l22   l16
6  1231231237   l31     l31   l31
```

Desired result

```
       CustomerI    V1       V2      V3
    1  1231231231   l22 I34  l22     l22
    2  1231231233   l7       l7 I19  l7
    3  1231231234   l31      l7      l31
    4  1231231235   l31 l7   l7      l31 l7
    5  1231231236   l16      l22     l16
    6  1231231237   l31      l31     l31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to use `gsub` to capture the two groups and then insert a space between them

```
dd[-1] <- lapply(dd[-1], function(i) gsub('([A-Za-z][0-9]+)([A-Za-z][0-9]+)', '\\1 \\2', i))
```

Comment: Thank you this works on my data. However I need for some reason to run it 2x because after first time code doesn't split longer ones such as I22I34I8I3I59 do you have any suggestion so everything is split with one line of code ? Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasJohnson You can try akrun's solution. It will work fine (I don't have time now to revise my ans with your new requirements - will do as soon as possible)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gsub` with regex lookarounds

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) 
                  gsub("(?<=[0-9])(?=[[:alpha:]])", " ", x, perl = TRUE))
```

Or with capture groups

```
df1[-1] <-  lapply(df1[-1], function(x) trimws(gsub("([[:alpha:]])", " \\1", x)))
```